# Why is Set not a property list type?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, swift4.2

I was trying to save a `Set<String>` type in User Defaults and got a 
"Attempt to set a non-property-list object" error..

which got me wondering, why is Set not a property list type?

Why are arrays and dictionaries allowed, but not sets?

Edit: I am aware of other ways to store my data. I'm just wondering if there is a known or estimated reason why Apple decided that Sets are not property list types.

Is it because Sets do not have keys like Arrays (index) and Dictionaries (key)? Is it because Sets are unordered? But Dictionaries are unordered as well..

Comment: What answer do you expect? Apple did not implement sets in property lists. It is  documented in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults what kind of objects can be stored in the user defaults.

Comment: I'm wondering why Apple didn't implement sets in property lists. Is it because they don't have keys? Does that make it difficult to hash or something?

Comment: I am not sure if that “why” can be answered. Property lists are similar to XML files, and Apple *could* have implemented a `<set>...</set>` element, similar to the `<array>...</array>`. Perhaps it has some historic reasons, perhaps there just was no need for it. – All that stuff predates Swift for many years, perhaps NSSet was introduced after property lists? I don't know.

Comment: I see. I guess we won't know until Apple tells us. Thanks!

Comment: When encoding `sets` and `arrays` there is no difference in practice.You can always convert a set to an array when encoding and to a set again after decoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Property lists represent data, not implementation details. An array is an ordered list. A dict is a mapping of string keys to values. What is a "set?" It doesn't mean anything special in simple text data. If the list cannot have duplicates, don't write duplicates. If it's unordered, ignore the order. Everything "set-like" has to do with manipulation of the data. (What behavior would you expect from a plist-set that actually *did* have duplicate elements? Would it be invalid? If not, how is it not just an array?)

Property lists are not a general object-tree serialization tool. That's what NSCoder is for. They're primarily designed for human-writable configuration like Info.plist, and to be parseable in any language. NSUserDefaults also is not a general purpose data-store (if it were, it'd be called "NSApplicationDataStore" or something like that). It was designed to store user configuration data in a way that users could hand-edit it.

The original (NeXTSTEP) format was much simpler to type:

```
SomeKey = {
    MyFirstProperty = ("here's", "a", "list");
    SomeOtherThing = "I'm a string";
};
```

Apple switched to XML with OS X, making it much harder to type, but the basic approach was the same. (During the early days of OS X, Apple made a lot of moves to integrate Java into the system, including more reliance on XML including [formal DTDs](https://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd). In retrospect, many of those moves were probably unfortunate, but they made sense at the time.)

Plists solve the same problems as JSON. They provide a minimal set of types that are are required to encode raw data, not data structures for implementing algorithms.

I'm not saying that plists were created from some mathematical first principles. If NSSet were an incredibly common type in configuration data, I'm certain that it would have found its way into the format. But they just weren't invented to be a generic way to save arbitrary application data, and neither was NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 0):

You need to archive your set first to make it a `Data` object. Only then you can store that data to your defaults.

Like so:

```
let sets: Set<String> = Set(arrayLiteral: "a","b","c")
let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: sets)
UserDefaults.standard.setValue(encodedData, forKeyPath: "test")
```

And then to unarchive your data, do it like this (and then you can get back your set)

```
if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "test"),
    let set = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? Set<String> {
    print(set)
}
```

As to the reason why you can't store your set without archiving, here's what Apple says:

> A default object must be a property list—that is, an instance of (or
>   for collections, a combination of instances of) NSData, NSString,
>   NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. If you want to store any
>   other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an
>   instance of NSData.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults

As you can see, if you convert your set to `Array` or `Data`, you'll be good to store it to `UserDefaults`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I'm aware of how to store non-property list data. I was just wondering why Sets were decided to be non-property list types.

Comment: By the way, 
`'archivedData(withRootObject:)' was deprecated in iOS 12.0: Use +archivedDataWithRootObject:requiringSecureCoding:error: instead`

Comment: Deprecated in iOS 12.0. If you're supporting iOS 12 and below (ex. 11.x), which you should be, you'll be fine.